# How can I extract a string between optional quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex, content-disposition

I'm using a Javascript regular expression to extract "filename" from Content-Disposition HTTP Header.

An example of Content-Disposition value is:

```
attachment; filename="myFile.pdf"
```

In some case the server does not enclose filename in quotes:

```
attachment; filename=myFile.pdf
```

Case 1 (OK):

```js
var contentDisposition = "attachment; filename=myFile.pdf" // get Content-Disposition from HTTP Header
const fileNameMatch = contentDisposition.match(/filename="?(.+)"?/);
const fileName = fileNameMatch[1];
console.log(fileName); // Expected: myFile.pdf - Actual: myFile.pdf
```

Case 2 (KO):

```js
var contentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"myFile.pdf\"" // get Content-Disposition from HTTP Header
const fileNameMatch = contentDisposition.match(/filename="?(.+)"?/);
const fileName = fileNameMatch[1];
console.log(fileName); // Expected: myFile.pdf - Actual: myFile.pdf"
```

In the Case 2 the expected result is: `myFile.pdf`
while actual: `myFile.pdf"` (last quote is not removed)

How can I fix the regular expression in order to get the Case 2 works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-greedy `+?` doesn't work before an optional, try an explicit class `[^"]`:

```js
 re = /filename="?([^"]+)"?/

 contentDisposition = `attachment; filename="myFile.pdf"`
 console.log(contentDisposition.match(re)[1])

 contentDisposition = `attachment; filename=myFile.pdf`
 console.log(contentDisposition.match(re)[1])
```

Another (and perhaps better) option would be to anchor the whole thing:

```js
re = /filename="?(.+?)"?$/

s = `attachment; filename="myFile.pdf"`
console.log(s.match(re)[1])

s = `attachment; filename=myFile.pdf`
console.log(s.match(re)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group matching an optional `"` with a backreference to match up with the double quote, and get the value from group 2.

```
\bfilename=("?)([^"\r\n]+)\1
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bfilename=` Match literally preceded by a word boundary
- `("?)` Capture **group 1**, optionally match `"`
- `([^"\r\n]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times any char except `:` or a newline
- `\1` Backreference to match the same as group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IoBFKy/1)

```js
var contentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"myFile.pdf\"" // get Content-Disposition from HTTP Header
const fileNameMatch = contentDisposition.match(/\bfilename=("?)([^"\r\n]+)\1/);
const fileName = fileNameMatch[2];
console.log(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions to parse HTTP field values is tricky.

To do it right, you'll have to consider more edge cases, such as as escaped quote in the string.

Comment: I know, but the code is inside an external Javascript library. So I submitted a Pull Request with just the fix of the existing regexp.